# How to get the set of left and right ancestors of a node with rpart

Tags: r, decision-tree, rpart

```
library(rpart)
head(iris)
Modele <- rpart(Species~.,
                data = iris,
                method = "class",
                parms =  list(split = "gini"))
```

I would like to know how can i get the set of left and right ancestors of a node with the package rpart

Comment: @kluu how to solve this problem ?

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question, to me, each node has only one ancestor.

Comment: @kluu If we take all the ancestors of a node, we want them divided between left ancestor and right ancestor, for example if we take a binary tree of depth 2, and we want to know the left and right ancestors of node 5, we will have:
left ancestor (5) = (1)
right ancestor (5) = (2)

Comment: Oh ok sorry I made the confusion with parents